# How to use the cursor in the new C++ Mongo Driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am using the new C++ driver to access MongoDB from my C++ program.
Through the tutorial I am able to fetch an entire collection from the DB.
I am also able to specify filters so I only get a few.

But once I get the collection data into the program, there is only a single example available for inspecting the data:

```
for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to know how to get the count of the collection
I would also like to know how to get number "i" in the return data, i.e.,:

cursor[i] or similar... which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for pointing out this oversight in our examples. If you would, please file a bug in the Documentation component at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX requesting that our examples include more detail on how to access data on the client.

You have two questions here, really:

- *How can I get a count*? The unhelpful answer is that you could probably write `std::distance(cursor.begin(), cursor.end())`, but you probably don't want to do that, as it would require pulling all of the data back from the server. Instead, you likely want to invoke `mongocxx::collection::count`.
- *How can I get the Nth element out of a cursor*? First, are you sure this is what you want? The obvious way would be to do `auto view = *std::next(cursor.begin(), N-1)`, but again, this probably isn't what you want for the reasons above, and also because the order is not necessarily specified. Instead, have a look at `mongocxx::options::find::sort`, `mongocxx::options::find::limit`, and `mongocxx:options::find::skip`, which should give you finer control over what data is returned via the cursor, and in what order.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's very helpful. But how do I know how many items I can skip if I don't know the total number of the items found? Say, I do a `find` with `limit(30)`, and I want to skip to the 25th document, but what if only 10 were found?

Comment: A note for readers is since the answer was written the `count()` on `mongocxx::collection` is actually deprecated. With modern driver releases you should be using [`count_documents()`](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#a80cf145d0add1ea987500dd01f3615f5) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks, acm!
I filed the bug and I figured out how to do it. To help others, let me post the two code examples here:

```
auto db = conn["db-name"];
int count = db["collection-name"].count( {} );
```

And

```
mongocxx::options::find opts;
opts.limit( 1 );
auto cursor = db["db-name"].find({ }, opts);

bsoncxx::document::view doc = *cursor.begin();  
std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
```